# Why is my bash loop to generate $i-$j_filename not working for the inner loop so that I only get four files (1-4_filename, 2-4_filename, ...)?

Tags: bash, file, loops, file-io, iteration

I have a reference file, "filename."  I have added the words "FIRST" and "SECOND" to it.  I now want to generate a number of files, where FIRST and SECOND are replaced by numbers and the files are named accordingly.  For example:

1-1_filename.txt, 1-2_filename.txt, 1-3_filename.txt, 1-4_filename.txt,
2-1_filename.txt, 2-2_filename.txt, 2-3_filename.txt, 2-4_filename.txt,
... And so on.

My code (below) is working to do the replacements and generate files, but I'm not getting all the files.  I'm only getting 1-4, 2-4, 3-4, and 4-4.  I have experimented for a few hours now and just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I would be grateful for any pointers.  Thank you.

```
    cp filename.txt filename_bak.txt

    for i in 1 2 3 4; do
        for j in 1 2 3 4; do
            sed s~"FIRST"~"$i"~g $i_filename.txt | sed s~"SECOND"~"$j"~g > $i-$j_filename.txt
        done
    done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a typo: `$i_filename.txt`

Your main issue is here:`$i-$j_filename.txt`. Variables are allowed to have underscores in them, so the variable being referenced is `$j_filename`. To avoid, add braces to separate.  Also, it is a bit more readable to have the entire sed command within quotes.  Here is a revised version of your script:

```
cp filename.txt filename_bak.txt
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    for j in 1 2 3 4; do
        sed "s~FIRST~$i~g" filename.txt | sed "s~SECOND~$j~g" > $i-${j}_filename.txt
    done
done
```

By the way, check out shellcheck.net.  That would have found your main issue for you.  I have a local executable version that gave me this error:

`script.sh|5 col 72 warning| j_filename is referenced but not assigned. [SC2154]`

Comment: Thank you very much, Jason!  I never would have figured that out.  I can't upvote your answer because my reputation is too low, sorry.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3292696 Glad to help.  Don't worry about it.